# Functions of the form $x^{p/q}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

What is known about functions like $x^{p/q}$, for positive integers $p,q$?

Considering a special case, $x^{1/n}$  for odd $n$ is defined for  $x \in \mathbb{R}$, while for even $n$ is defined only for $x\geq 0$. What is the domain of the general form $x^{p/q}$?

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to think of this as solving $y^q = x^p$. This has a solution unless $x^p$ is negative and $q$ is even. This happens if $x<0$ and $p$ is odd, so we can summarize:

If $p$ is odd and $q$ is even, the domain is $x\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.
Otherwise, the domain is $x\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks, so if $p/q$ is is in reduced form then the function is defined for $x \geq 0$ for even $q$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$ for odd $q$. What can we say about the domain of the function $x^a$ for real $a$? Any textbook to recommend?

Answer (score 2):

It's best to assume that $p/q$ has been reduced as much as possible meaning $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime.

You are close based on your observation of the special case $1/n$.

By definition, $x^{p/q}=(\sqrt[q]{x})^p$ so if $q$ is even, we must have $x\geq0$ and if $q$ is odd there is no restriction on $x$. By the assumptions on $p$ and $q$ it is no different to instead consider $x^{p/q}=(\sqrt[q]{x^p})$.

These functions are all continuous on their domain and differentiable except possibly at $x=0$ and you can work out in what cases they are/are not differentiable at $x=0$.